Base and delta sync params in Amplify request mapper
I'm working on an Android project and using Amplify for the backend. Amplify using Dynamodb as data source. I'm trying to trigger a query instead of scan during base sync. So I modify QuerySyncModelNameDataResolverFn function, add index for query using GSI.
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "Sync",
  "index": "index-name",
  "query": #if( !$util.isNullOrEmpty($queryValue) )
                $util.toJson($queryValue)
           #else
                null
           #end,
  "filter":   #if( !$util.isNullOrEmpty($filter) )
                $util.toJson($filter)
              #else
                 null
              #end,
  "limit": $util.defaultIfNull($args.limit, 100),
  "lastSync": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNull($args.lastSync, null)),
  "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNull($args.nextToken, null))
}

It's working fine for the base sync but failed for the delta sync because of the index. My question is which param to check is it base sync or delta sync? index part should be null for delta sync.
